# Suppress deprecation warning for one line of code? (C++)

Tags: c++, suppress-warnings

How do you suppress the deprecation warning for one line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should accomplish what you're trying to do.

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: WARNING_CODE) //4996 for _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
// Insert deprecated code here
#pragma warning(pop)
```